# Using setVisibility in Android?

Tags: java, android

According to android docs,
`void setVisibility(int visibility)` has One the following parameters `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE`, or `GONE`.

```
View dp2 = findViewByid(R.id.title);
dp2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

So why do we have to use `View.GONE`, instead of `dp2.setVisibility(GONE);`

Comment: Because `GONE` is defined in `View`.

Comment: GONE, what is it ? View.GONE is a constant defined in View Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GONE` is a `static` field on the `View` class.

If your code has `import android.view.View`, you reference `GONE` as `View.GONE`.

If your code has `import static android.view.View.GONE` — a [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) — you can reference `GONE` simply as `GONE`.

Comment: can u explain why are we using classname.variable instead of obj.variable ? my understanding is that to reference a method or variables we should use its object to reference it

Comment: @Xerazm: `GONE` is a **`static`** field on the `View` class. Usually, to refer to a `static` field, you use what you describe as "classname.variable". [The Java documentation covers `static` fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 1):

if you are in a class that extends View or `extends` any class that `extends View`, then you can directly use `GONE` without using `View.GONE`, but if you are in a class that does not extend any `View` then you have to use `View.GONE` , that is because `GONE` is a constant defined in the class `View`

Comment: Thank you   for your help